# NotImplementedError: `create()` must be implemented

Tags: django

If you see here, please stay. Thank you very much

#### report errors：NotImplementedError: `create()` must be implemented.

#### this's my class:

```py
class BookCreateView(CreateModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        return self.create(request)
```

But there are already crate() out of CreateModelMixin
So why does it report an error?

Comment: Can you show what `BookSerializer` is?

Comment: class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):                                                                            
    # bnum = serializers.IntegerField()                                                                                 
    bname = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)                                                
    b_pub_date = serializers.DateField()                                                   
    bcomment = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)                                  
    bimage = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

Comment: That error is from the serializer. You need to add a `create` method in your serializer for `CreateModelMixin` to work. Were you looking to use this for a model? If so have a look at [`ModelSerializers`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Comment: I understand. Thank you